# combine data according to different date

Tags: r

I have a question about how to combine/select data according to different date.
When I download data from database, I have to combine data according to its date. I wonder how to achieve it in R. For instance, my dataset called d is as below:

```
date_A  A    date_B  B
150215  10   150215  12
150216  9    150218  8
150217  10   150219  9
150218  10   150220  11
```

Now I want to combine A and B to create a new variable c which contains the A and B data from SAME date. My goal is to create a C like this:

```
date    A    B
150215  10   12
150218  10   8
```

Here the C will match A and B according to date atomically.
How can I achieve it in R?

Comment: merge(data1, data2, by = date)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the merge statement:

```
merge(df[1:2], df[3:4], by.x = "date_A", by.y = "date_B")

  date_A  A  B
1 150215 10 12
2 150218 10  8
```